# What exactly is the gauge invariance in relation to Higgs Field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, gauge-theory, higgs, gauge-invariance

I have been studying about the "theoretical need for Higgs Boson" and the historical overview discusses about how theory of gauge invariance questioned the reliability of theories of electromagnetism and weak interaction and also entailing that several particles with mass had to be massless.

Can anyone explain to me what exactly that means and how it led to the hypothesis of Higgs field?

Comment: You're basically asking for a review of quantum field theory, gauge theory *and* the Higgs mechanism. This appears to be *too broad* to be covered in any amount of detail by an answer on this SE. We have parts of this already covered though: For gauge theories, see e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126978/50583, for the Higgs mechanism, see e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17944/50583

Comment: Required reading:  [Why the Higgs Field is Necessary](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/how-the-higgs-field-works-with-math/4-why-the-higgs-field-is-necessary/)